# Sharepoint define search scope using csom

Tags: 2013, search, client-object-model

I have a sharepoint installation with multiple site collections, let's say siteA, siteB e.t.c

I am using the following code to search in sharepoint

```
    using (ClientContext context = Connect())
    {
         KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(context);
         keywordQuery.QueryText = "text to search";
         SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(context);
         ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
         context.ExecuteQuery();
     }
```

and the results i am getting are from all sites siteA, siteB etc.
Is there anyway to specify that i want the search to be performed only in siteA and to be even more specific only in Shared Documents of siteA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search scopes have been replaced by Result Sources in SP2013.

To specify a result source you'll want to set the source ID on the Keyword Query to the GUID of the result source. E.g.:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

 var keywordQuery = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery(context);

 keywordQuery.set_queryText("Search Query");

 // Set Source ID (GUID)

 keywordQuery.set_sourceId("XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX");


 var searchExecutor = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.SearchExecutor(context);

var results = searchExecutor.executeQuery(keywordQuery);

context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySuccess, onQueryFail);
```

Additional Search CSOM examples can be found [here](http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2014/01/sharepoint-2013-search-javascript-csom-primer/).

Comment: Yes i know the concept of search scopes. How do i find the GUID of a search scope once i create it?